# How prove: for every convex polygon there exist three consecutive vertices which their circumcircle include all polygon?

Tags: geometry

How prove that for every convex polygon there exist three consecutive vertices which their circumcircle include all poligon?

Comment: You might try induction; I haven't thought through the details, but the base case is immediate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show that a convex polygon is contained within the largest circle determined by three consecutive vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1742400/show-that-a-convex-polygon-is-contained-within-the-largest-circle-determined-by)