# Show that a convex polygon is contained within the largest circle determined by three consecutive vertices

Tags: geometry, circles

> Given a convex $n$-gon. The circumcircle is constructed for every triple of consecutive vertices of the polygon. We get the $n$ circles. Select the circle with the largest radius. Prove that the circle contains the polygon.

**My work so far:**

$n=3 -$ triangle - obviously.

$n=4 -$

If $\angle B = \max \left\{A,B,C,D \right\}$ then $ABCD \in \omega_{ABC}$
[image]

$n\ge 5$. I need help here.

Comment: Perhaps induction on the number of sides?  You can construct the three new circles associated with one new point and prove that either the old circle contains the new polygon, or one of the new ones does, and probably prove something about the radii at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crux of the argument is contained in the following proposition.

**Proposition 1** Let $p$ and $q$ be points in the plane, $H$ be one half-space separated by the line through $p$ and $q$, and $D$ be a disk with $p$ and $q$ on its boundary and centered in $H$. If point $r\in H$ forms a circumcircle with $p$ and $q$ that has a smaller radius than that of $D$, then $r\in D$.

See the configuration in this proposition in the figure below. Any circle through $p$ and $q$ has a center on the line orthogonal to the line through $p$ and $q$ and passing halfway between those points. For that circle to have a radius smaller than $D$ and be centered in $H$, the center must be on dotted segment between $c$ (the center of $D$) and the midpoint between $p$ and $q$. And we can see that the portion of any such circle that is in $H$ (the dotted circle in the figure) is contained in $D$.

[image: diagram of proposition 1]

Next, we establish that ``adding vertices'' to a polygon only increases the size of the largest circumradius formed by consecutive vertices.

**Proposition 2** Let $P$ be a polygon with vertices in clockwise order $v_0$, ..., $v_{n-1}$ and let $P'$ be a polygon with vertices $v_0$, ..., $v_{n-1}$, $v'$ (where $v'$ is not necessarily listed in clockwise order). The largest circumradius of three consecutive vertices of $P'$ is at least as large as that for $P$.

Assume the largest circumradius for $P$ is formed by vertices $v_{i-1}$, $v_i$, $v_{i+1}$. If $v'$ does not occur between vertices $v_{i-1}$ and $v_{i+1}$, then those vertices remain consecutive and thus the largest circumradius associated with $P'$ is at least as large as $P$. So we focus on the case that  $v'$ causes $v_{i-1}$, $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ to no longer be consecutive. Without loss of generality, suppose $v'$ lies between $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$. Now there are two cases each providing a larger circumradius of a new set of consecutive vertices:

1. If $v'$ lies inside the circumcircle of $v_{i-1}$, $v_i$, $v_{i+1}$, then the circumradius of $v_i$, $v'$, $v_{i+1}$ is larger.
2. If $v'$ lies outside the circumcircle of $v_{i-1}$, $v_i$, $v_{i+1}$, then the circumradius of $v_{i-1}$, $v_i$, $v'$ is larger.

[image: diagram of proposition 2]

Now we can proceed to the main result. Let $P$ be a convex polygon with vertices $v_0$, $v_1$, ..., $v_n$ ordered in clockwise order. Without loss of generality, assume that $v_0$, $v_1$, $v_2$ form the largest circumcircle of any three consecutive vertices of the polygon.

The proof follows by induction, evaluating the sequence of polygons $P_i$ with vertices $v_0$, ..., $v_i$. The base case holds trivially for a single triangle $P_2$. The inductive step involves adding a single new vertex $v_i$ to the polygon and checking that vertex lies in the circumcircle of $v_0$, $v_1$, $v_2$. Proposition 2 ensures that $v_0$, $v_1$, $v_2$ provides the largest circumradius for each polygon, i.e., the largest circumradius for $P_i$ cannot be realized by a different set of consecutive vertices.

We complete the result by applying the Proposition 1 with $p=v_0$, $q=v_1$, $r=v_i$, and $D$ being the circumcircle of $v_0$, $v_1$, $v_2$. Convexity of the polygon ensures the assumptions of the proposition. Specifically, $v_2$ and $r$ must lie in the same half-space and the center of $D$ lies in the same half-space as $v_2$.